# When parent props are being updated in react Redux dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following scenario.
!Please do not suggest to implement it differently, because it is a simplified example of my case. Also don't look for syntax issues.

I have two components. A parent and a child

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
parentFunc = () => {
    const  { someObject } = this.props;

    // Here someObject will have the updatedValue????
}

render() {
    return <Child parentFunc={this.parentFunc} />;
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      someObject: state.someReducer
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parent);


class Child extends React.Component {
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { someSyncAction, parentFunc } = this.props;
    
    someSyncAction();
    parentFunc();
}

render() {
    return <div>Some content here</div>;
}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
someSyncAction: () => dispatch(syncAction()), 
});

export default connect(
null,
mapDispatchToProps
)(Child);
```

Which is the value of someObject after componentDidUpdate is being called in child?

Comment: No, it will not have the updated value until the next render. It doesn't matter that it is synchronous, the `props` will not change until the component re-renders, and it will not re-render in the middle of a function all (`componentDidUpdate`).

Comment: Thank you a lot for you response. If change the code to
new Promise((resolve) => {
     resolve( someSyncAction(););
}).then(() => {
    parentFunc();})
it works. Why?